# SumIf function in Vba with variable columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do a sumif formula, but am having difficulties. First, I want to move to the cell next to the last cell on row A3. My first part seems to accomplish that. Second, I want to do a sumif formula (sumif(range,criteria, sum_range)) where the value lands on the active cell. However, I can't seem to get the formual to work. My number of columns can change so I can't have that be constant. I want the range to be from G1 through the last active column (i.e. JW1 or some other value instead of JW), my criteria to be the letter "M" and my sum range to be G3 through the last active column, which would match the last active column in my first range. Then, I want to autofill down to the last row, where my first range is locked, but the sum range isn't locked.

```
Sub Sumif()


Dim lastColumn As Range
Dim NextlastColumn As Range

lastColumn = Range("G1" & Column.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
NextlastColumn = Range("G3" & Column.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
Range("A3").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).Select

ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIF(lastColumn,{"M"}, NextlastColumn))"


End Sub
```

Comment: I don't follow the last requirement. Your sum range is an entire column so filling *down* won't be affected whether the range is absolute or not.

Comment: I intend my sum range to be a row over a number of columns. Then for my autofill to fill down the rows on the column that has the sum if function

Comment: I've accomplished my goal, but a bit backwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you just want something like this:

```
Sub Sumif()

Dim lastColumn As Long

lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Cells(3, lastColumn + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(R1C3:R1C" & lastColumn & ",""M"",RC3:RC" & lastColumn & ")"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer but it isn't the way I wanted it to work. I did a normal sum if function way far out to the right and then did another macro that deletes blank columns afterwards.

```
Sub Netpay()
' netpay Macro

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("KU1").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "Net Pay"

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A4:D4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Job Cost").Select
    Range("KU3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(R1C8:R1C305,""M"",RC[-299]:RC[-2])"
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIF(R1C8:R1C305,""M"",RC[-299]:RC[-2])-SUMIF(R1C8:R1C305,""N"",RC[-299]:RC[-2])-SUMIF(R1C8:R1C305,""S"",RC[-299]:RC[-2])-SUMIF(R1C8:R1C305,""T"",RC[-299]:RC[-2])"
    Range("KU3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("KU3:KU" & lastRow)
End Sub
```

And then this

```
Sub DeleteBlankColumns()

Dim lColumn As Long
 Dim iCntr As Long
 lColumn = 1000
 For iCntr = lColumn To 1 Step -1
 If Cells(1, iCntr) = "" Then
 Columns(iCntr).Delete
 End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: One nice thing, if it's what you like, is that the above keeps the formula intact. You can still hit F2 and see the live formula vs. just a number in that cell that is the answer.